# rtq query invalidatesTags / provideTags middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Возможно ли конфигурировать  invalidatesTags / provideTags так чтобы не проверять на наличие ошибки каждый раз?

invalidatesTags: (_result, _error) => (_error ? [] : [{ type: 'TagName', id: 'LIST' }]),